# "I have this in language X, implement/help in language Y" - how do I respond?

Tags: discussion, scope

This is a question I came across just now:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139636/angularjs-how-to-show-hide-busy-indicator

The user has implemented a busy indicator in jQuery already and they want help in implementing it in Angular. The user also has linked code for the indicator

In general, this seems to be a 'write this code for me' question, which signals me to flag as 'too broad' and ask the user to go to a freelancing site or something.

Is this the correct approach? I have a feeling this question could be also answered with something like 'learn angular and then attempt' or even a nudge in the right direction with some minimal code, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I've since flagged as too broad, as further discussions seemed to generate too much content which will/won't be useful only to the OP.

Comment: I also tend to close such questions as _too broad_.

Comment: Code translations and the like are almost always too broad.  If there are well-scoped, specific questions that arise while the OP is translating code then that's ok.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I also think there's nothing we can really do to help - if for example you know enough C to write a Notepad type program, then once you learn enough Java there should be no issue for you to write a similar program(ignoring, of course, difference in libraries and all that). There is no question to ask at all - just unfamiliarity to a new language.

Answer (score 8):

A code-translation-question is actually two questions, which are both off-topic:

1. What does this code do?
2. Please code this for me in $language.

As an additional problem, it might not be obvious which part of the behavior of the original program is an arbitrary and unneccessary limitation (and how far those limits may be lowered) or just the original programmers discretion, and which parts are actually important.

While I prefer closing as "too broad", both "unclear" and even "no mcve" are quite reasonable close-reasons.