# Is it unwanted to attract inactive communities to SO by asking and answering basic questions on the topic myself?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm a member of several neuroscience simulator communities ([neuron-simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neuron-simulator), [nest-simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nest-simulator)) that require extensive programming to develop software, computational models of the brain. These communities have not seen much activity on SO, most likely because the software was created in the 1990's and none of the knowledgeable members happened to be frequent SOers, so they opted for forums (uncurated, diluted, quasi-dead) and mailing lists (not public info) and the SO communities never took off. They are both the most used tools in their fields.

I'd want to transcribe frequent and relevant questions on these topics to SO in order to attract more traffic and to help these communities self-organise on SO.

However, I received a close vote on a very [basic question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66511457/1016004) and it made me worried. I can see that it is very minimal, but it's a basic operation with a non-intuitive solution that is not directly covered in the documentation of the tool and would be one of the first things new users bump into and benefits from a curated clear answer here on SO.

Before I fully commit to building up a knowledgebase of questions and answer here, I wanted to ask Meta if this somehow not advisable? I am worried because some of my questions when glanced over by someone outside of these communities can quickly be deemed as unfit (which will be pretty much everyone since there are no veteran high-rep SOers moderating these communities).

I don't think propping up or gamifying my basic questions to make them look more passable in the review queue to outsiders helps the spread of information. Other basic questions on different topics are also short and silly, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty?rq=1), but at one point in time the information wasn't on SO and had to be asked.

I'll be very unlikely to attract up votes in these efforts initially and very likely to attract down/close votes, and am worried, what would you advise me to do?

From the help center on [on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

I think these questions will check all those boxes.

---

A PS on the question itself: For many neuroscientists creating a synapse is a basic operation that would be semantically equivalent to something like `part1.connect(part2, connection=synapse)` but in this simulator it is a non-trivial multistep solution that involves parts of which you have no way of knowing you need them, it is also not documented as such. (There's like an old tutorial part 2, step 5 that shows how to do it)

Comment: That question is not clear at all you're about to solve a programming problem.

Comment: How could I improve that? Would adding "using its Python interface" or something like that help? I'm also thinking about other requirements like to "show research effort" but I find that hard to do in a Q&A style answer.

Comment: I editted it, I'll pay extra attention to the basic requirements of questions, do you think that that is sufficient to avoid the net negative effect of Q&A'ing on low traffic tags?

Comment: Perhaps this old blog post will give you some good direction too:[It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). The *real* key, in my opinion, is that even though your aim is to self answer, post the question as if you aren't going to, ensuring you give all the details you normally would, including a [mre] (if applicable) so that other can answer it too, even if you already have.

Comment: @Larnu yes, I see some self-answers where the question doesn't really make any sense without the answer. Sometimes it's just incomplete "I'm trying to do X. How?" other times it's so very hyper specific that you *cannot* answer without the code base. A good self-answered question should be a good question to start with and allow others to also answer it.

Comment: The premise that the votes have anything to do with the paradigm or that it is unwanted is incorrect

Comment: Yea, that seems to be the consensus, I'll just focus on improving the question quality and trust in the reviewers ;) I do still think that other very old and short questions with 10k+ upvotes are treated very differently, but perhaps when asked today they'd be treated more stringently as well.

Comment: Note that *"how do I"* type questions are not well received if more context of what you do know is not given. They often sound like .."I want a tutorial" which is antithetical to SO purpose

Comment: "would be one of the first things new users bump into and benefits from a curated clear answer here on SO" - if you have a good reason to believe others will have that question, then that's a fine reason to post a question (self-answered or not). If this is done for the purpose of getting users of some language or tool to engage on SO, that's fine too. However, that's not to say anything about whether the specific question you asked or the specific topic you asked about is okay.

Comment: The "how do I" as @charlietfl put them is often not received well. Some of us prefer those though, so it's very prone to opinion. The issue is that they are often closed for "lack of focus" (proxy for "lack of effort") even if they are very focused. Some have tried to stress to not close those posts. [Why was my code translation question closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403116/) may be a good read on that. Along with [Got review ban for reviewing as 'Looks OK' for a question which I still think is OK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401146/)

Comment: The question you asked (after it was edited) seems *fine* to me. You asked how to do something, provided a short example of what you mean and showed some research: that's basically everything a question should do (although I don't have any domain knowledge and I can't comment on whether adding any additional context or explanation would make sense). But some users just don't like such short and/or basic questions. In some cases I would agree and say even the most basic introduction to the topic would answer that question, but I have no idea whether that applies here.

Comment: I want to clarify that the other question you linked is from __2008__. It's hella old, and no longer an accurate representation of what is, and isn't off-topic on SO.